# phone:WebBrowser how we can set Auto Height and Width?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

```
   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

                <TextBlock x:Name="articleDate" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" 
                           Text="Timefzdsaf" />
                <Image x:Name="image" Stretch="Uniform" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <phone:WebBrowser Name="webBrowser1"                            
                          IsScriptEnabled="False"  Background="White"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                          VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 

                        ></phone:WebBrowser>



            </StackPanel>
```

phone:WebBrowser will not show in my page(if am not giving Height and Width i want it should take automatically). can any one help me to show html in phone WebBrowser?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the StackPanel. Try Grid with RowDefinitions. For WebBrowser set it to "*"

From your code (added Source just to demonstrate):

```
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock x:Name="articleDate" 
                       Foreground="Black" 
                       FontSize="20" 
                       Text="Timefzdsaf" />
            <Image x:Name="image"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   Stretch="Uniform" />
            <phone:WebBrowser Name="webBrowser1"  
                              Source="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/"
                              IsScriptEnabled="False"  
                              Grid.Row="2"
                              Background="White"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   
                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                              VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                              HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
            </phone:WebBrowser>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: Hi Banepa thanks, i have tried with the same but my grid is working fine. I have give some HTML Text in WebBrowser which is taking by default ScrollViewer(it should take full height not show in Scroll bcz after that i have show advertisement).I have given ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" in WebBrowser but still which i don't want Scroll Viewer WebBrowser.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve. If you want to make your HTML content to take the full height of WebBrowser when you can try add meta tag to your html <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=no">. To disable vertical scroll at all use in css: body {-ms-touch-action: none;}